# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setIgnorePagination(Z)V

Tags: dynamic-reports

I am new to [dynamicreports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/datafilterreport.html), the example can be found at the link, but it gives me the following exception.

Please help me to find the issue.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setIgnorePagination(Z)V

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be sure that you are using the correct version of the libraries.
http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/requirements.html

In your case you have an error with jasperreports. With DynamicReports 3.0.2, the jasperreports correct version is 4.7.0 or above